# Clang exposes variable names on -O3 (but not on -O2)

Tags: android-ndk, clang

I'm using Android NDK, Revision 13b. The clang version is 3.8.256229.

When I use the clang toolchain with `-O3` or `-Ofast` compiler flag to build a shared library, global variable names become externally visible. This doesn't happen at `-O2` or below or when using the GCC 4.9 toolchain.

How can I make sure that the symbols get stripped properly when using clang?

Compiler flags (armeabi-v7a target):

`-O3 -Wall -D__ANDROID__ -fvisibility=hidden -Wl,-s -Wno-sometimes-uninitialized -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-unknown-attributes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -Wl,--gc-sections -std=gnu++11 -fno-rtti -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16`

Linker flags:

`-O5 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-s -march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8`

Comment: Could you file a bug with a test case? https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/new

Comment: I tried to write a minimal test case, but I was unable to replicate the issue. I made a separate project with the same kind of structure (with a JNIEXPORT function to make sure everything wouldn't be optimized away) and it hid the variables correctly. Unless there is a bug related to code size or something then I have no idea what could be causing this problem. The shared library that I'm having the issue with uses two static libraries and links to the GLESv2, OpenSLES, android and log libraries if that provides any clues.